# Lock Mouseclick and curserselection until event in a Tree in Qooxdoo / javascript

Tags: javascript, locking, user-input, qooxdoo

Theres a tree list in a class, and its data gets recalculated and rearranged sometimes. And now I want to lock the user input for the time of calculation, so the user can't choose another item (changeselection is the qooxdoo event triggered on selection of a list item) until the calculation is done.

any suggestions?

best regards, Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qooxdoo way to do this is to set the `enabled` property of the widget to *false*.

E.g. with a tree widget:

```
var t = qx.ui.tree.Tree();
t.setEnabled(false);
```

You can read up on the `enabled` property in the API doc of [qx.core.Widget](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.core.Widget~enabled).

Comment: this would work, but it blanks out the list.. so its not visible until you activate it again :(

Comment: my fault- I forgot the "()"

so- this.getMyList().setEnabled(false); does the job! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `blocker`, search in demo.qooxdoo.org for `blocker` or simply use `setEnabled(false)` as previousely suggested.

Answer (score 0):

One option that comes to my mind straight away is using `IFrame` on top of the tree with `100% transparency` or `0%  Opacity`, and hide the `iframe` when your processing is finished.

Don't know about Qooxdoo though... It would work in any simple web application

Comment: thanks for this, i'll figure out if it works for my specific situation! very creative! :)

Comment: this won't work because of the optional keyboard item selection with keyboard up- or down!